# Make query inner query result selectable

Tags: mysql, sql, function, select, nested

I was wondering if it is possible using MySQL to somehow, wrap the select of the inner query so that the outer query can use it in its where clause.

```
SELECT  
`FirstName`,
`Surname`,
`AddressLine1`,
`AddressLine2`,  
`AddressLine3`,  
`AddressLocale`,
`AddressRegion`, 
`AddressZip`,
`AddressCountry`,
`CopyShipAddress`
FROM  `Contacts` 
WHERE `EEID` 
IN 
(SELECT CONCAT_WS(',', `Sender`,  `Receiver`,  `Buyer` ) AS EEID_list
FROM  `Transactions` 
WHERE  `TransactionID` = 3)
```

`Sender`,  `Receiver` and  `Buyer` are EEIDs. Perhaps there is a function other than CONCAT_WS I can use that will provide me with this functionality.

Comment: can you add the sql fiddle with little data set it would be easier to identify

Comment: you may try GROUP_CONCAT

Comment: GROUP_CONCAT(`Sender`, `Receiver`, `Buyer`) returns '125992602'.

Which is actually 1 2599 2602 in my database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dont use concat_ws records on IN query , it may not give correct data

**concat_ws may work perfectly for IN query with integers but may not work for strings because they need to be enclosed in quotes '**

try below instead

```
SELECT  
`FirstName`,
`Surname`,
`AddressLine1`,
`AddressLine2`,  
`AddressLine3`,  
`AddressLocale`,
`AddressRegion`, 
`AddressZip`,
`AddressCountry`,
`CopyShipAddress`
FROM  `Contacts` 
WHERE `EEID` 
IN 
(
select Sender as eeid FROM Transactions WHERE TransactionId=3
UNION ALL
select Receiver as eeid FROM Transactions WHERE TransactionId=3
UNION ALL
select Buyer as eeid FROM Transactions WHERE TransactionId=3
 )
```

Comment: Thanks timus2001. The result isn't a problem as I can get it using a join simply enough. I'm looking for a specific function that can do as requested.

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up on CONCAT_WS.

Comment: Thanks, I think I'll move on and go with your answer.